# python - all subsets of a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, subset

```
input set [1,2,3]
```

with itertools.combinations we get following output with this program

```
>>> a = []
>>> x = [1,2,3]

>>> for t in range(1, len(x)+1):
...     k = itertools.combinations(x,t)
...     a.append([y for y in k])
```

i get following output

```
[ [(1), (2), (3)], [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)] ]
```

but i am looking for this output:

```
[ [(1), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3)], [(2), (2, 3)], [(3)] ]
```

any idea who to get this output.

Comment: Do you really want the two levels of list nesting?  Or do you only care about the order of the tuples?

Comment: Why that particular order?

Comment: order of the tuples

Comment: I was trying to solve a question from problem where 1 form all subset first in increasing order then leaves 2 and then pick 3 and form all subset (in increasing order). Then 2 repeat the same process and so on

Comment: The output you claim to get isn't what you actually get. Copy and paste what you actually get.

Comment: Same with your desired output, btw, that's also not really what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that produces a *flattened* list (as you indicated was acceptable in your comment) of the combination tuples, in the desired order:

```
def combos(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return []
    cs = combos(x[1:])
    return [(x[0],)] + [(x[0],) + c for c in cs] + cs
```

If you invoke it as:

```
print(combos([1, 2, 3]))
```

The result is:

```
[(1,), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3), (2,), (2, 3), (3,)]
```

Again, this is a *flattened* list, but the tuples are in the order you requested.

Comment: A beautiful example of recursion!

Answer (score 1):

You could just flatten and sort it:

```
sorted(sum(a, []))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [[(1,), (2,), (3,)], [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)]]
>>> sorted(sum(a, []))
[(1,), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3), (2,), (2, 3), (3,)]
```

Comment: clever! but it will not work when i can't sort the array as originally i have an array of string (food names) and i am trying to form combination but i can't sort it because combinations need to be formed in the order in which input is given by the user. But as per my question above this is also right. Thanks.